# Pygame: window resizing infrequently

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a little problem with the pygame event system. Calling set_mode(...) makes events of type VIDEORESIZE come up very infrequently. I was able to reproduce this in a little script similar to the pygame resize example from the docs:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

pygame.init()


flags = HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|RESIZABLE
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300), flags)
screen.fill(WHITE)
pygame.display.flip()


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type is QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type is VIDEORESIZE:
            # Version 1: do nothing
            #pass
            # Version 2: set_mode
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.size, flags)
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Version 1: working as expected, all VIDEORESIZE events are shown, the white surface is not rezising.

Version 2: all events **except** 95% of the VIDEORESIZE events are shown, the white surface is resizing whenever a resize event comes up (the first one to three of them always pop up instantly, probably only first pygame.event.get() call).
Everything else is working just fine.

SW/HW, single/double buffering does not make any difference.

[image: Version 2, black borders, surface not resizing]

Python 3.7.3
Pygame 1.9.5
Linux Mint 19.2
Cinnamon 4.2.4
Linux 4.15.0-66

There were other posts here but they either did not call set_mode or had other 'symptoms'

Thanks for your help!

Edit: Works on Windows 10, even though there is only one resize event per drag, so no 'live resizing'. Seems to be a pygame bug, any ideas how to get around it?

---

Comment: I've not had this issue on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04, Cinnamon), using much the same code.  The only difference I see between my code and the OP's code is the use of `is` instead of `==` (the two operators are not equivalent).  The `is` operator is for comparing whether two variables "point" to the same object, not comparing equivalency.   Although the code is question is probably only comparing enumerated types.

Comment: In case of primitive data types it seems to be pretty much the same and I prefer this way :) Besides the other if expressions are working just fine as well, so this does not seem to be the problem...
Maybe, it is related to the X window manager or a dirty implementation by pygame as mentioned before, too slow to run fluently on my (weak) laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who experience the same issue, here is a mostly functioning workaround (at least on my linux machine):

Calling set_mode() only when the user releases the mouse button prevents pygame from spamming the window manager. This way there is no 'live resizing' while dragging but the VIDEORESIZE events pop up much more frequently.

```
[...]
elif event.type is pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
    resized = True
    updateSize = event.size
elif event.type is pygame.ACTIVEEVENT and resized:
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(updateSize, flags)
```

If it is not working, check if there is an ACTIVEEVENT when you release the mouse button after dragging the window border. Also note, that this will cause the window size to jump to the size of the last received resize event (which can differ from the actual size if resize events are infrequent again).